# How to monkeypatch (mock) calls to ncurses crate?

Tags: rust, mocking, ncurses, monkeypatching

I come from Python where you have `monkeypatch` in `pytest`, so I refer to the operation I want to do as monkeypatching, however, I've been told that the actual operation is called mocking more generally.

Anyway, my application uses the [`ncurses`](https://crates.io/crates/ncurses) crate, and I need to test some code that calls it. How would I monkeypatch (mock) the calls to crate's functions, methods, and other attributes properly?

For example,

```
fn get_page(&self, commands: &[String]) -> Vec<String> {
    match commands
        .chunks(ncurses::LINES() as usize - 3)
        .nth(self.page as usize - 1)
    {
        Some(cmds) => cmds.to_vec(),
        None => Vec::new(),
    }
}
```

How would I patch the `ncurses::LINES()` call?

Answer (score 0):

In python everything is dynamic and patchable, but rust is compiled and concrete.  So in your source code you have to explicitly decouple your working code and the library code.

```
trait NcursesImpl {
    // all functions in ncurses that you want to use need to have implementations here.

    /// Here is a default implementation that just delegates to ncurses
    fn LINES(&self) -> c_int {
        ncurses::LINES()
    }
}
struct DefaultNCruses;
impl NCursesImpl for DefaultNCurses {
    // no functions overridden, everything uses default implementations
}
struct LinesLiarNCurses {
    lines: c_int,
}
impl NCursesImpl for LinesLiarNCurses {
    /// overrides default implementation for debug purposes
    fn LINES(&self) -> c_int {
        self.lines
    }
}
```

`get_page()` has to change slightly to use a NCursesImpl instead of the bare ncurses.

```
fn get_page(&self, nc: &NCursesImpl, commands: &[String]) -> Vec<String> {
    match commands
        .chunks(nc.LINES() as usize - 3)
        .nth(self.page as usize - 1)
    {
        Some(cmds) => cmds.to_vec(),
        None => Vec::new(),
    }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure where the NCursesImpl object should live.  Here I've made  it an explicit parameter of the get_page call, but it might actually belong as a member of `Self` in the struct that has the `get_page` impl.  You might want to store it in a `Box<dyn NCursesImpl>` so that you don't have type parameters littering your data structures.